# Barra de navegacion problema con dropdown

Tags: html, css

Quiero que me desplegué el dropdown únicamente cuando pase por Productos pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. Ya intente creando la clase CUADRADOFLOTANTE2 para cuando pase por ahí se despliegue pero nada, la única forma que conseguí es que cuando pase por cualquier parte de la barra se despliegue, agradecería la ayuda ya que estoy iniciándome y quiero solucionar esto. Tuve que borrar algunas partes no importantes del codigo para poder publicar xD

```
<body>
 <div class="CUADRADO">
            <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Inicio</a></span>
            <div class="CUADRADOFLOTANTE2">
                <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Productos</a></span>
            </div>
                <div class="CUADRADOFLOTANTE">
                    <p><a href="#">Automoviles</a></p>  
                    <p><a href="#">Trailers</a></p> 
                    <p><a href="#">Camionetas</a></p> 
                </div>
            <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Punto de venta</a></span>
            <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
body {
background-color: #e7e7e7;
margin: 0px;
}

.CUADRADO {
background-color:rgb(218, 218, 218);
display: block;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
min-width: 140px;
cursor: pointer;
left: 97px;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE a{
text-decoration: underline rgba(0,0,0,0.65);   
text-align: left;
padding: 18px 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 1.1rem;
color:#000;
display: block;
}
.CUADRADOFLOTANTE p {
margin: 0px;
}
.CUADRADOFLOTANTE a:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.9);  
}

.TEXTO a:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.9);
}

.CUADRADO:hover .CUADRADOFLOTANTE{
display: block;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE2 {
display: inline-block;
}

</style>
```

Lo que pienso es que alguna parte esta mal ubicada o que falta alguna clase mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Te hace falta un contenedor en `CUADRADOFLOTANTE2` y aplicar el estilo en ese nuevo contenedor.

Por ejemplo agregando un `div` con clase `CONTENEDOR` (Por cierto te recomendaría cambiar todas las clases a minúsculas, pero lo dejo como lo tienes).

```css
body {
background-color: #e7e7e7;
margin: 0px;
}

.CUADRADO {
background-color:rgb(218, 218, 218);
display: block;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
min-width: 140px;
cursor: pointer;
left: 97px;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE a{
text-decoration: underline rgba(0,0,0,0.65);   
text-align: left;
padding: 18px 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 1.1rem;
color:#000;
display: block;
}
.CUADRADOFLOTANTE p {
margin: 0px;
}
.CUADRADOFLOTANTE a:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.9);  
}

.TEXTO a:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.9);
}

.CONTENEDOR:hover .CUADRADOFLOTANTE{
display: block;
}

.CONTENEDOR {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="CUADRADO">
    <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Inicio</a></span>
    <div class="CONTENEDOR">
      <div class="CUADRADOFLOTANTE2">
        <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Productos</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="CUADRADOFLOTANTE">
        <p><a href="#">Automoviles</a></p>  
        <p><a href="#">Trailers</a></p> 
        <p><a href="#">Camionetas</a></p> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Punto de venta</a></span>
    <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por ayudarme, lo tendré en cuenta lo de utilizar palabras minúsculas en las clases

Answer (score 2):

El contenedor de clase `CUADRADOFLOTANTE2` debe abarcar enteramente también el contenido de `CUADRADOFLOTANTE`, y no de manera separada. He dado solución corriendo el cierre del contendor, de manera tal que ahora pueda verse de la siguiente forma:

```css
body {
background-color: #e7e7e7;
margin: 0px;
}

.CUADRADO {
background-color:rgb(218, 218, 218);
display: block;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
min-width: 140px;
cursor: pointer;
left: 97px;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE a{
text-decoration: underline rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
text-align: left;
padding: 18px 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 1.1rem;
color:#000;
display: block;
}
.CUADRADOFLOTANTE p {
margin: 0px;
}
.CUADRADOFLOTANTE a:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.9);
}

.TEXTO a:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.9);
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE2:hover .CUADRADOFLOTANTE{
display: block;
}

.CUADRADOFLOTANTE2 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="CUADRADO">
         <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Inicio</a></span>
         <div class="CUADRADOFLOTANTE2">
            <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Productos</a></span>
            <div class="CUADRADOFLOTANTE">
               <p><a href="#">Automoviles</a></p>
               <p><a href="#">Trailers</a></p>
               <p><a href="#">Camionetas</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Punto de venta</a></span>
         <span class="TEXTO"><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></span>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buena primera respuesta! Te recomendaría "encerrar" con comillas inversas los nombres de las clases para darles formato de código. Da gusto ver usuarios nuevos que leen las normas del sitio y redactan buenas respuestas! Voto a favor!